# Create an invisible view that is interactable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, hidden, alpha, invisible

For prototyping I am looking to create a invisible interaction area.

- If I set the alpha to 0, you can't interact withit.
- If you set it to
  hidden, it also does not receive gesture events.

Comment: How about _not_ creating the view and just tracking the gesture? As soon as you want to show it you can create it at the position you have tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use a View for this, Instead you could just use a UIButton and set frame to your current view's frame & set its background color to clearColor like below,

```
self.invisibleButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This will do the same action & reduce little works like adding Tap gesture and setting some properties for the view if you go with View.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to set the background color to an invisible color. You can't see the button but you can interact with it.

In the init I put:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView enable userInteraction and make clear background color

```
UIView *viewsample=[[UIView alloc]init];
viewsample.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
viewsample.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
viewsample.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:viewsample];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapSkip = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(iviewsampleClicked:)];
[viewsample addGestureRecognizer:tapSkip];
```

method called when it touched

```
-(void)iviewsampleClicked:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture{

}
```